# Problems Comparing Two Methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to compare data that I get from two different methods: the first one from an instance method, and the second from a class method. I get one incomprehensible warning and one error.

**This is the interface:**

```
@interface RadioStation : NSObject {

NSString *name;
double frequency;
char band;

}
+(double) maxFMFrequency;
-(void) chackFrequency;

@end
```

**This is the implementation:**

```
@implementation RadioStation

+(double) maxFMFrequency {

return 107.9;
}
-(void) chackFrequency {

    switch (band) {
        case 'F':
            if (self.frequency > [[self RadioStation] maxFMFrequency] ) //  in this line i get the warning and the error massage
                frequency=107.9;
            break;


@end
```

And this is the **warning** I get:

`instance method '-RadioStation' not found  (return type defaults to 'id')`

And when I build and run the program I get the **error**:

`Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Should read:

```
if (self.frequency > [RadioStation maxFMFrequency] )
```

Self is not needed to address the class, if addressed by name. If you want to reference self you could use:

```
if (self.frequency > [[self class] maxFMFrequency] )
```

Comment: @shaynagar In the code you posted your "`chackFrequency`" method has no closing curly brace. If your actual code is like that then that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

it isn't clear from your post where the values for band and frequency come from, so I just stuck them in the init method for testing purposes, and this code worked fine when I called alloc init on this class:

```
@implementation RadioStation

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        band = 'F';
        frequency = 120;
        [self chackFrequency];
        return self;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}

+(double) maxFMFrequency {
    return 107.9;
}

-(void) chackFrequency {
    switch (band) {
        case 'F':
            if (frequency > [[self class] maxFMFrequency] )
                frequency=107.9;
            NSLog(@"%f",frequency);
            break;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: @shaynagar If rdelmar's answer answered your question you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your error is as follows:

```
[[self RadioStation] maxFMFrequency]
```

change it with

```
[RadioStation maxFMFrequency]
```

Comment: an error could be that uses frequency without first initialized in your if statement

Comment: self.frequency you call, but actually you have not created the property for this variable